# Automation crash on XP with latest sp3 and updates

Tags: c++, windows-xp, ui-automation

I have a class that is using Windows Automation. It works fine on newer OSs (like 7 - 8 and 8.1) but on Windows XP (using SP3 and latest updates it crashes).

The code that produces the crash is:

```
void CUIAutomationClient::Initialize()
{
  try
  {
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    HRESULT hr; 
    hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(CUIAutomation), NULL,
             CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
             __uuidof(IUIAutomation),
             (void **)&g_Automation);
    if(FAILED(hr) || g_Automation==NULL) 
    {
      CoUninitialize();
    }
  }
  catch(...)
  {
  }
}
```

Do you have any suggestion how to fix this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: please give a better definition of 'crash': what errorcode/whatexception is thrown? or is abort called or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirements section of the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee671406.aspx) states the following minimum requirements:

> Windows 7, Windows Vista with SP2 and Platform Update for Windows Vista, Windows XP with SP3 and Platform Update for Windows Vista [desktop apps only]

It seems quite plausible that you have not installed the Platform Update.

Comment: The Platform Update for Windows Vista  was missing. Thanks.

Comment: Hello, Can you please tell me if there is a way to verify if windows xp has Platform Update for Windows Vista installed

Comment: @Dan.Gurghian I'm sorry, I don't know the answer to that.

Comment: After installing this update it works perfectly. Link:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971513